# Gradle project dependency not working

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Can some one please help me in below:

I am using `RTC` and checkout `Gradle` project, but at the end when I am checking the properties and looking for source folder for my build, I am getting nothing.

Also I am not send the repository specific Gradle jars. What i am doing wrong?
I tried including external jars but no luck as their are too many jars.

Error: project is not at all building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on your project then configure and convert it to gradle project.
Refresh and you will see all dependencies.

Comment: ohhk..i did it and it worked , but why it did not take it as gradle project when i checked out it?